# Doesn't want Python Shell popping up

Tags: python

- Using Mac OS 10
- Python Version: 2.7.7
- PyGame version: 1.9.1

Okay. So first off, I am learning a great python game programming series by Sentdex on thenewboston's channel on Youtube. Well, whenever I run the module, the pygame window pops-up. But the Python Shell also pops up, which I really don't want. Besides, the creator of the game programming series doesn't have the Python Shell pop-up. How do I change this setting?

[image]

PS: I searched on google and found nothing, and I checked in the python preferences...

Comment: Is this really that bad? IMHO it shouldn't bother you in development phase; If you start your script from the command line, via some start up script or double click on the .py/.pyw file, the shell shouln't appear.

Comment: Thanks. I thought it would cause problems down the road.

Comment: Nope, shouldn't. But you can use it to display usefull debug information ;-)